# Share users across drupal8 sites

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am a newbie to Drupal and I'd like to share user information across multiple Drupal8 sites.

I changed the settings file for the subsite as mentioned in https://www.drupal.org/node/22267.

This is how my prefix array looks like.

```
'prefix' => array(
         'default' => 'test_',
         'users' => 'shared_',
         'sessions' => 'shared_',
         'user_revision_user_picture' => 'shared_',
         'shortcut_set_users' => 'shared_'
    ),
```

After reloading the page, I still cannot login using the users which I created in the shared site and I am able to log in using the username and password which I specified during the installation of the test site.

Are there any tables which I am missing? I have tried restarting nginx.

Comment: You are unlikely to get specific answers to your question for Drupal 8 as it is still in Beta and has changed a lot from previous Drupal versions, making us all Drupal 8 newbies. Also, the link you provided is very old (2005, updated 2011) though I believe it would probably still work for Drupal 7.  I suggest if you are new to Drupal, maybe use Drupal 7 instead of 8.

Comment: I'm trying out the user sharing feature for Drupal 7. I'll answer this question with the solution for Drupal8 if I can make it work later on.